# Using free() with a dynamically allocated complex pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to have a function that allocated a complex double array, perform some operations and return the last value calculated. Although the calculations are fine, I'm having issues when I try to free the allocated space. During execution I get the "double free or memory corruption" error. I am using the standard  library.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <assert.h>

double complex main()
{
    // Declare fixed number of steps.
    int number_of_elements=10;
    // Reserve memory for array.
    double complex *complexArray = calloc(number_of_elements,sizeof(double complex));
    // Verify if allocation was successfull.
    assert(complexArray!=NULL);
    // Fill first position with number and start counting
    complexArray[0]=1+2*I;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        complexArray[i+1]=2*complexArray[i]; // Simple operation
        printf("The complex number stored in position %i is %f+i%f\n\n",i+1,creal(complexArray[i+1]),cimag(complexArray[i+1])); // Print the current number
    }
    double complex output=complexArray[i];
    assert(complexArray!=NULL); // Check if pointer is not NULL again
    free(complexArray); // Program fails here
    complexArray=NULL;
    return output;
}
```

I changed the data type from "double complex" to "double" and it works. Is there any way to free the complex array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote behind the memory you allocated. The last loop iteration uses `i=9` and writes to `complexArray[i+1]` which is not in your allocated range. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with `free()` itself.

Issues like that should be possible to discover with valgrind for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your free() in regards to  double complex *complexArray = calloc() looks correct. Keep in mind the array is zero-based starting with 0, double check your indexes, specifically:

complexArray[i+1]=2*complexArray[i]; // Simple operation

as that would result in the first output to be:
The complex number stored in position 1

I suppose your loop could throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS that way.